# One GitHub protection rule that matches main and feature branches?

Tags: github

I would like to have one expression in the branch protection rule that will match both `main` and all the feature branches like `feature/foo`.

When I use `*` it applies to `main` only, and when I use `*/*` it matches only feature branches.

Is there a way to match all branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is not possible. GitHub team is aware of that and the only way is to create two protection rules.